# Error "??? ???" when installing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, system-installation

I have a problem installing Ubuntu 16.04.1 on my PC: I'm trying to install it using a USB flash drive.

The problem occurs when, after selecting the language and picking the "Download updates while installing" and "Install third-party software [...]" buttons I press continue: after one or two minutes the operation stops and a message box containing the words "??? ???" appears. Soon after a system problem is detected.

[image]

I've tried with different languages, with or without internet connection, with or without the third-party software, but nothing changes! The problem remains the same.

*Specifications*
  ASUS N56VM
  6GB RAM
  Core i7 processor
  nVidia GeForce 630M with 2GB RAM
  Windows 10 installed on 500GB hard drive

Comment: Do you have FakeRAID by any chance?

Comment: No, I don't have FakeRAID.